# cs50 sandbox for-loop issue

Tags: c, for-loop, get, char, cs50

I want to make a program that, when I give it a number, it counts from it downwards.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
 
int main(void) {
    int i = get_char("Choose a number.\n");
    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
         printf("a\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: `printf("%d\n", a);`

Comment: the problem is it just says a a a a a a a a a a.

Comment: @El_Moroccan Why are you using get_char instead of get_int?

Comment: thx, but is there a way to make it count downwards ?

Comment: @El_Moroccan Does "a a a a a a a a a a" mean that it is glad or disappointed?

Comment: $ make project2
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    project2.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o project2
$ ./project2
Choose a number.
6
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a

Comment: thats the output

Comment: Also, note the char code of `'6'` is 54.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp He should be glad that his system does not use the EBCDIC coding where the character 6 has the value 246.:)

Comment: when you correct the code to use: `get_integer()` rather than `get_char()`  then add a check to assure the resulting value is > 0

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You're `printf`ing "a", not the value of the variable a. Try:

   ```
   print("%d\n", a);
   ```
2. You're not counting down from `i` to 1; you're counting up from 0 to `i-1`. You want something more like:

   ```
   for (int a = i; a >= 1; a--)
   ```

   (And if you want to count down to 0, obviously, change that 1 to 0.)
3. You're reading a character, but you want to read an integer:

   ```
   int i = get_int("Choose a number.\n");
   ```
4. And you're not returning anything from a function that is supposed to return an `int`.

   ```
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: There is a typo print("$d\n", a); Must be %d instead of $d.

Comment: And reread the comments anew. It will be useful for you.

Comment: *Two things:* or maybe 4 things?

Comment: You can omit `return 0;` in `main` function if you are using C99 or later.

Comment: OTOH, even though you're allowed to omit `return 0;`, it is still, IMNSHO, better to explicitly return a value from `main()`, even at the end.